# SYS_TIME capability now working in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When I created a pod with below security context having permission to change system time am getting error

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-sleeper
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "4800"
    image: ubuntu
    securityContext:
     runAsUser: 1010
     capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_TIME"]
    name: ubuntu
```

I am getting error that cant set date operation not permitted.

```
master $ kubectl create -f ubu.yml
pod/ubuntu-sleeper created
master $ kubectl exec -it ubuntu-sleeper -- date -s '19 APR 2012 11:14:00'
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Thu Apr 19 11:14:00 UTC 2012
command terminated with exit code 1
master $
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change system time, you will have to run the container as root:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-sleeper
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "4800"
    image: ubuntu
    securityContext:
     capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_TIME"]
    name: ubuntu
```

Comment: Any clue why I cannot run as non-privileged user in this case? It looks like it was possible in k8s lower than 1.21

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you move the user up to the pod level

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-sleeper
  namespace: default
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1010
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "4800"
    image: ubuntu
    name: ubuntu-sleeper
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_TIME"]
```

Comment: no, cause then container just inherits the same 1010 from pod level anyway