# How does Kubernetes implement Linux capabilities?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, security-context

Linux capabilities is applied to an executable. If I add capabilities to a container, what does it mean?
This is my container securityContext:

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 1008
  capabilities:
    add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
```

But my task can't create raw socket. So shall I apply capabilities to the executable when packing docker image?

Comment: Can you try to delete
runAsUser: 1008 line from the code ? See examples: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container

Comment: @Malgorzata Yes. I found capabilities only works with root account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have adviced you in comment section, I am posting it as an answer:

> Starting with kernel 2.2, Linux has divided privileged processes’
> privileges into distinct units, known as capabilities. These distinct
> units/privileges can be independently assigned and enabled for
> unprivileged processes introducing root privileges to them. Kubernetes
> users can use Linux capabilities to grant certain privileges to a
> process without giving it all privileges of the root user. This is
> helpful for improving container isolation from the host since
> containers no longer need to write as root — you can just grant
> certain root privileges to them and that’s it.

See: [linux-cap-kubernetes](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/defining-privileges-and-access-control-settings-for-pods-and-containers-in-kubernetes-2cef08fc62b7).

Part of your code under container section should look like this:

```
securityContext:  
  capabilities:  
    add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
```

To run some capabilities (in your case perform various network-related operations) you have to run container as root. See example: [capabilities-securitycontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616892/sys-time-capability-now-working-in-kubernetes).

Read more: [linux-capabilities-securityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#capabilities).

Comment: My test result shows that runAsUser+capabilities didn't work. But I can't find any description. So I am not sure if this is a bug or not

Comment: To run some capabilities (in your case perform various network-related operations) you have to run container as root - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616892/sys-time-capability-now-working-in-kubernetes. I have edited my answer, take a look.